# Are native menu bars for MacOS supported in Qt Quick?

Tags: macos, qt, menu, qtquick2

in a project I'm working on I've got to the point where I need a menu bar (File, Edit, View etc.) to interact with. I work on a Mac and so I want to be able to use the menu bar already provided in OS X, but from all the documentation I've seen and questions that have been answered it looks like that is only supported properly in QMainWindow, a part of Qt Widgets and not Qt Quick. Are native menu bars supported for Mac in Qt Quick, or will I have to write some platform-specific code to implement one? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have to go to extra lengths to use a non-native menu on OS X, in fact — and menus don’t need a QMainWindow at all anyway. In a nutshell: menus on OS X are native, unless you force them not to be.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm aware of that, but how do I create a menu bar in Qt Quick that will go up to the actual OS X menu bar, and not just create a bar that runs along the top of my app? I haven't found any way to do so, and I'm wondering if it's supported.

Comment: They probably should do it by default... I'm surprised that they don't.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qt-labs-platform-menubar.html. The only bad thing about it is that everythint in qt labs might not work in a future version of qt and then it really bites.

Comment: Is there an actual answer to this question? I want to start a new application using Qt Quick and cannot get a system menu bar. In the old style applications, I would do:
' menubar->setParent(nullptr) '
and get the menu bar of the application widget to become the menu bar at the top of the screen as expected from a Mac OS app.

Comment: @Michel You can do that same thing from the C++ side, while having the GUI in QML, works fine.

Comment: @mlvljr I have done that. Though I am quite frustrated with an implementation detail that was changed for the benefit of systems without windowing that make pop-up menus such as the ones ComboBox generate being clipped by the surrounding Qt Quick widget. That means I am restricted to not put any into my QML widgets and to find alternatives whenever I need to present the user with a list of choices.

Comment: @Michel CRazy thought: use a frameless QML view for the combobox overlays!
(..and never ever sleep well since then :) )

Answer (score 0):

Like **Rolf Winter** [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353997/are-native-menu-bars-for-macos-supported-in-qt-quick#comment91749250_52353997), you can have a native Mac OS Menu Bar with Qt Quick / QML, without using Widgets. It comes from [MenuBar QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-menubar.html).

Sure, it is a Qt Labs component, so there is certain risk of using it in production (*no guarantee/stability*).

Here's a simplified example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.platform 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500
    minimumWidth: 500
    height: 300
    minimumHeight: 300
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Testing Mac OS native Menu Bar in Qt Quick")

    MenuBar {
        id: menuBar

        Menu {
            id: fileMenu
            title: qsTr("File")

            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Ololo")
                onTriggered: console.debug("ololo menu item clicked")
            }

            // this one won't show up in File menu because of its `role`,
            // and it will actually appear in the main menu - under the application name,
            // where you'd usually expect About menu to be
            MenuItem {
                //text: qsTr("About")    // no need to set the text,
                role: MenuItem.AboutRole // because it gets generated
                onTriggered: console.debug("show your About window")
            }
        }

        Menu {
            id: editMenu
            title: qsTr("Edit")

            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Stuff")
                onTriggered: console.debug("stuff menu item clicked")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your question is about Mac OS, so I didn't do anything to make the menu cross-platform (*for instance, on Windows you might want to move About menu item to Help menu and actually give it some text*).

Anyway, on Mac OS the result will be the following:

[image: Mac OS Menu Bar created with Qt Quick]

As you can see, `Edit` menu also gets populated with a couple of "bonus" items (*not sure if that is handled by Qt or Mac OS*).

Just in case, my environment:

- Mac OS 11.5.2
- Qt 5.15.2

Comment: To ensure you're getting the Labs version when you're also using Quick Controls, qualify the type names. For example, if you "import Qt.labs.platform as Labs", use "Labs.MenuBar", "Labs.Menu", and "Labs.MenuItem". Otherwise you may get the non-native menu types, and wonder why nothing works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could even try getting it from cpp by adding a QMenuBar and then attach the menus you want, like File, Edit etc. Take a look at this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html
I did this because i wasn't using the **ApplicationWindow** from QML but a custom one which is derived from **QQuickWindow**.